# Umbraco 7 Session value not set in Surface Controller and Class File give error "" object not set instance of reference ""

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

When I tried to set value in session its give me error:

> object not set instance of reference

This is my code, when I call this methods it's give me above error

```
public ActionResult TestSesion()
{
    try
    {
        Session["test"] = "test";
        string sessionValue = Session["test"].ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        throw ex;
    }

    return null;
}
```

But if I set session value in .cshtml page its working perfectly.